# Slim Application Error type- Twig_Error_Loader

Tags: php, slim

I am newbie to slim framework and working on a live video streaming app. This one is my first ever question i am adding to stack overflow account. I have installed application and added all the necessary requirement dependencies with composer. I am facing following issue when i am opening application on xampp localhost

Error:

```
Type: Twig_Error_Loader
Message: Unable to find template "C:/xampp/htdocs/local/dev/templates/routes/home/home.twig" (looked into: ./templates).
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\local\dev\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Loader\Filesystem.php
Line: 215

Trace
#0     C:\xampp\htdocs\local\dev\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Loader\Filesystem.php(139): Twig_Loader_Filesystem->findTemplate('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\local\dev\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php(264): Twig_Loader_Filesystem->getCacheKey('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\local\dev\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php(322): Twig_Environment->getTemplateClass('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', NULL)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\local\dev\vendor\slim\views\Twig.php(87): Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\local\dev\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\View.php(255): Slim\Views\Twig->render('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', NULL)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\local\dev\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\View.php(243): Slim\View->fetch('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', NULL)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\local\dev\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Slim.php(757): Slim\View->display('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\local\dev\templates\routes\home\home.php(16): Slim\Slim->render('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Array)
#8 [internal function]: {closure}()
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\local\dev\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Route.php(468): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\local\dev\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Slim.php(1357): Slim\Route->dispatch()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\local\dev\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\Flash.php(85): Slim\Slim->call()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\local\dev\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride.php(92): Slim\Middleware\Flash->call()
#13     C:\xampp\htdocs\local\dev\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions.php( 67): Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride->call()
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\local\dev\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Slim.php(1302):     Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions->call()
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\local\dev\index.php(12): Slim\Slim->run()
#16 {main}
```

I am not getting what actually the error is. My site is secured with **https** on localhost as that was the requirement of my client. I have installed SSL certificate for my xampp projects but still on https too this problem arises.

My xampp version v3.2.2 and php 5.6.19

Do anyone have faced the same issue before. Thanks in advance for quick response.

**update**: [image: folder structure]

**update 2**

this is my config file i use the slim

```
 $app = new \Slim\Slim([
        'view' => new \Slim\Views\Twig()
 ]);
 $view = $app->view();
 $view->parserExtensions = [new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension()];
 $mongo = new MongoClient();
 $app->db = $mongo->local;
 $app->device = new Mobile_Detect;
```

**Update3**

```
$app->get('/', function() use ($app){
$path = templatePath(__FILE__);
$templateData = [
    'pageTitle' => 'Home',
    'UI' => [
        'noSidebar' => true
    ]
];
$app->render("$path/home.twig", $templateData);
})->name('home');
//templatepath function that returns the path to $path variable
function templatePath($file) {
return str_replace(getcwd().'/templates/', '', dirname($file));
}
```

Comment: Sorry to be devil's advocate, but have you checked you can open `C:/xampp/htdocs/local/dev/templates/routes/home/home.twig` using that exact path?

Comment: yes it is working if i add the exact path in another window. i can see the code in my browser i have written on that page

Comment: So the problem does not appear when open the website with ``http``?

Comment: the same error appeared their as well on http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell from the traceback, it can not find the template. I think the reason for that is because all paths are relative to the path that was passed to the Twig constructor.

For example, if I passed `templates/views` when I instantiated Twig, and my Twig file was located at `templates/views/home.twig`, all I would have to do is `$app->render("home.twig");`.

**Update**

Looking through the projects I've done with Slim 2, it looks like when you instantiate Slim, you can pass another option that specifies the `root` of where Twig will look for templates. So consider the following code:

```
$app = new Slim([
    "view" => new Twig(),
    "templates.path" => "path/to/views/folder",
]);
```

After doing that you then be able to as I stated above.

**Update 2**

Rereading the error message you posted, I noticed that it is looking at `./templates`. Now assuming that `/templates` is the same `templates` folder posted in the question, you could use the relative path to the twig file, which would in this instance be `routes/home/home.twig`. Now anywhere you are trying to render a twig file would just have to do `$app->render("routes/path/file.twig");`, of course editing the path to the file you actually want.

**Update 3**

Just for completion, the final code would look something like this:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim([
    "view" => new \Slim\Views\Twig(),
    "templates.path" => "/../templates/routes"
 ]);
$view = $app->view();
$view->parserExtensions = [
    new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension()
 ];
$mongo = new MongoClient();
$app->db = $mongo->local;
$app->device = new Mobile_Detect;
```

Then anywhere you would like to render a view you would do this:

```
$app->render("home/home.twig");
```

**Edit 1**

In response to the comment about a template function. Taking a look at your directory structure, there isn't really a need for a function of you just combine the code above and then get the filename from `basename(__FILE__)`.

Comment: $app = new \Slim\Slim([
 'view' => new \Slim\Views\Twig()
]);
$view = $app->view();
$view->parserExtensions = [new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension()];

Comment: my folder structure  i have updated in my question pls see this

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer containing the final code.

Comment: its says directory does not exist..   The "/../templates/routes" directory does not exist.

Comment: i just simply changed render path ..Thnks

Comment: I have updated question a little. The resolution is quite simple but for the whole project adding hard-coated path would be difficult for me. Could u please provide the suggestion for the templatepath function that returns me same path but when i use that it shows me the very first error i posted.